# Current Location to destination using mapview or google maps for the iphone iOS Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, direction

SO I am a totally new and do not know where to begin. I basically want to create a view that shows the users current location and directs them to my set location (park, concert, business, etc.).  It seems fairly simple but there is so much smoke and mirrors online that I do not know where to start or how to finish. Would it be easier to call to google maps or use the mapview in the SDK?

And the bigger question is how do you do this? I mean I can create simple views and load webviews but I can not figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directions are part of the Maps application and are not available in the MapKit API. To give your users Google Maps directions, you need to use the Maps URL scheme, as documented in the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1). Specifically, you need to include the `saddr` and `daddr` parameters in the URL, which specify the start and destination addresses for a directions search, respectively. I believe you can pass latitude/longitude coordinate pairs (comma-separated) for those parameters, but you’ll have to experiment a bit to find the correct formatting and order.

Comment: I think this would be my best option, but how do I connect this to a button to launch goolge maps application?

Comment: OK so I figured out the code, was having a brain fart there, the only thing I need to figure is how to have the starting location be the users "current" location.

Answer (score 1):

Use MKMapView .. its fairly straightforward to set up -- you can get the current location from CLLocationManager and pass its coordinates to the map view.

http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this website http://www.martip.net/blog/localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps
it will help you with the current location thing.

Answer (score 0):

By "direct" do you mean actually show a path for how to get there?  That there is no API for.  You can place a pin anywhere on a map to show people where something is, but they have to figure out how to get there themselves.

The term you are looking for to add points to a map is adding Annotations to an MKMapView.

Comment: Well I was just looking for a pin point location, I know you cant have turn by turn nav or anything, but I know when you use google maps you can get a shaded line connecting the to pin points thats basically what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this website it may help you http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial